# What is meant by "infinitely often" in this problem on Borel sets?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets

As the title suggests, I am having some trouble understanding an exercise regarding   Borel sets.  In particular I am trying to

> Show that the set of real numbers that have a decimal expansion with
>   the digit $5$ appearing infinitely often is a Borel set.

My question here is what is meant by the phrase "infinitely often" in this case?  I have never seen this phrase before in a formal context. This attempt of mine is horrific so don't butcher me, but I tried starting out in the following way:

> Let $\mathcal{A}_5$ denote the set of real numbers that have a decimal expansion with the digit $5$ appearing infinitely often, i.e. every $a\in\mathcal{A}_5$ can be written as $$a=\ldots+ 5\cdot10^n+5\cdot10^{n-1}+\ldots+5\cdot 10 +5+5\cdot10^{-1}+\ldots 5\cdot10^{-m-1}+5\cdot10^{-m}+\ldots$$

Am I interpreting "infinitely often" correct here?  If not, what is it trying to say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrase means just this; if $$a_k 10^k + a_{k-1} 10^{k-1} + \dots + a_0 + a_{-1} 10^{-1} + a_{-2} 10^{-2} + \cdots$$
is the decimal expansion of a real number, then the set
$$
\{ n : a_n = 5, -\infty < n \leq k \} 
$$
is an infinite set.

---

Pulled up from the comments below: to elaborate, the given condition means that there is some infinite subsequence of $5$'s in the sequence $( a_n )$.

Take care that it does *not* mean that all $a_n$'s are $5$, or that all $a_n$'s after a certain point are $5$. For example, you could have that $a_n = 5$ whenever $n$ is even and $a_n = 7$ whenever $n$ is odd. This is a number whose decimal expansion contains infinitely many $5$'s, but it also contains infinitely many non-$5$'s.

Comment: So, in other words, there is some infinite "string" of $5$'s in each number in this set of real numbers?

Comment: @ThyArtisMath Yes, there is some infinite string in the sequence $( a_n )$. Take care that it does *not* mean that all $a_n$'s are $5$, or that all $a_n$'s after a certain point are $5$. For example, you could have that $a_n = 5$ whenever $n$ is even and $a_n = 7$ whenever $n$ is odd. This is a number whose decimal expansion contains infinitely many $5$'s, but it also contains infinitely many non-$5$'s.

Comment: Got it!  Thank you for the example -- that makes sense to me now!

Comment: @ThyArtisMath Glad to be of help. :)

Answer (score 3):

"Infinitely often" means "infinitely many times".  In other words, of all of the digits in the decimal expansion of your number, infinitely many of them are $5$.  It doesn't mean that all of them are $5$, or even that "most" of them are $5$ in any sense, just that there are infinitely many $5$s.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  Thank you for the clarification.  Would you happen to have any suggestions for a way in which I can explicitly write such a number mathematically?  Or do you think that writing that out would be unhelpful in this case?

Comment: I doubt such a representation would be helpful.  That would be essentially writing your set as the image of some function, but that is not likely to be helpful for showing it is Borel since an image of a Borel set under a Borel function need not be Borel

Comment: Ah ok, I did not know that.  Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

The requisite concept for the problem of infinite 5s in the decimal expansion of a real number is the limit supremum of a sequence of sets:
$$
S=\limsup_{n \to \infty} A_n = \bigcap_{n \geq 1} \bigcup_{j \geq n} A_j.
$$
The meaning of $S$ is that $x \in S$ iff x is in infinitely many $A_j$. A useful suggestion by Robert Israel as to how to construct the $A_j$ is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3825229/1235568). My quibble with the answer is that the $A_j$ can be constructed using open intervals. The endpoints can be excluded since they have a decimal expansion with a finite number of 5s.