# Show that the set of real numbers that have a decimal expansion with the digit 5 appearing infinitely often is a Borel set.

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, borel-sets

> Show that the set of real numbers that have a decimal expansion with the digit 5 appearing infinitely often is a Borel set.

Let $E$ be the set of all real numbers that have a decimal expansion with the digit 5 appearing infinitely often. To show that $E$ a Borel set, first we need to verify that $E$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. First to show that $E$ is closed under countable intersections, take $r_1, r_2, \dots \in E$ and note that their intersection will be the infinite subsequence of 5s. Thus the countable intersection is in $E$. Similarly for countable unions, the countable union contains the infinite subsequence of 5s so it is in $E$ too. Thus $E$ forms a $\sigma$-algebra.

I am wondering if my approach is good in first showing that $E$ is $\sigma$-algebra and then showing that it is a Borel set. Assuming that I showed correctly that $E$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, I am not sure on how to show the last step, that $E$ is a Borel set. I think the direction I have to go in is to translate between the decimal expansion of real numbers and how they can be written as open subsets.

Comment: wouldt it be easier to prove the complement of this set is a borel set?

Comment: $E$ is a set of real numbers.  A $\sigma$-algebra is a collection of sets.  So $E$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra, nor do you want it to be.

Comment: You need to show that $E$ is an element of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open sets.

Comment: It makes no sense to talk about the intersection of a bunch of real numbers.

Comment: @RobertIsrael so I want to show that E is an element in the collection of open sets of the $\sigma$-algebra. What is the connection between decimal expansions of real numbers and open sets though?

Comment: @EvanKim No, $E$ is not an open set.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: The set $E_1$ of real numbers that have a decimal expansion where the  first digit after the decimal point is $5$ is the union of $[n+ 0.5, n+0.6]$
and $[-n-0.6, -n-0.5]$ for $n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$ ($0.6$ is included because $0.6 = 0.5999\ldots$).  This is a closed set: its complement is open. Generalize to $E_k$ involving the $k$'th digit.  Express your set as a countable intersection of countable unions of these.

Answer (score 0):

Robert Israel, Thank you very much for your hint.

I am reading "Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler.
This exercise is Exercise 10 on p.38 in Exercises 2B in this book.

My solution is here:

> Let $E_k$ be the subset of real numbers that have a decimal expansion where the $k$-th digit after the decimal point is $5$.
> A closed set is a Borel set.
> So, a union of countable closed sets is a Borel set.
> And $E_1$ is a union of countable closed intervals by Robert Israel's hint.
> So, $E_1$ is a Borel set.
> Similarly, $E_k$ is a Borel set for each $k\in\{2,3,\dots\}$.
> Since the collection of Borel sets is a $\sigma$-algebra, $E=E_1\cup (E_2\setminus E_1)\cup (E_3\setminus (E_1\cup E_2))\cup\dots$ is a Borel set.

Is my solution ok?